# designing different-2 DAO or single DAO on spring

Tags: spring

i want to design DAO interface i have department table with dept_id, Employee Table with dept_id and employee_id ,project table with employee_id and report table with employee_id. Now requirement is that i want to do this thing in `spring` so i  m confused should i make different DAO for each table or one generic DAO that contain all implementation logic of all table ,if its generic what are the methods should i give please help me out on designing interface

i have make EmployeeDAO interface but i have to make project and report and department table all are loosely coupled i have done with EmployeeDAO i m showing my EmployeeDAO interface here

```
 package com.ankur.tutorial.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.ankur.tutorial.employee.model.Employee;

/**
 * The employee DAO is the main Data Access Object that will allow to retrieve
 * and update the employee objects from and to the database. The retrieve and
 * update is done in a manner that employee, the projects and reporting
 * associated are updated
 * 
 * 
 */

public interface EmployeeDAO {
    /**
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     * 
     *             Returns all the employees from the database along with
     *             projects and reportigns.
     * 
     * @return List of all employees.
     * @throws
     */
    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

    /**
     * Search for an employee by name. The name will match either the first name
     * or the last name. The matching is done using the SQL expression LIKE
     * %name%
     * 
     * @param name
     *            The name to search for
     * @return The list of employees with matching name.
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     */
    List<Employee> findEmployees(String name);

    /**
     * Select employee by ID.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            The ID (Number) of the employee
     * @return The employee with employee number matching the id
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     */
    Employee getEmployee(long id);

    /**
     * Update the employee and the associated project and reporting to the
     * database.
     * 
     * @param employee
     *            The employee to update
     * @return true if the employee record is updated
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     */
    boolean updateEmployee(Employee employee);

    /**
     * Delete the employee and the associated projects and reportings.
     * 
     * @param employee
     *            The employee to be deleted.
     * @return true if the employee record is deleted
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     */
    boolean deleteEmployee(Employee employee);

    /**
     * Create employee, project and reporting records in the database.
     * 
     * @param The
     *            employee to be created
     * @return true if the creation is successful
     * @throws EmployeeDAOException
     */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DON'T* make one DAO that manipulate all tables. Period.

Ok, one more sentence.  How are you suppose to maintain if you are enhancing your system and adding more and more table. Your super-all-in-one DAO will be HUGE.

Comment: one more question how can we use  one data source in different dao without using getJdbcTemplate() method right now i m using getJdbctemplate() and ref the data source in xml to each DAO impl